# Excel formula to extract numbers from string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel it contains two types of string

1. (423) 242-0045 begin_of_the_skype_highlighting (423) 242-0045 FREE     end_of_the_skype_highlighting
2. (630) 472-1900 begin_of_the_skype_highlighting (630) 472-1900 FREE end_of_the_skype_highlighting, (773) 878-7340 begin_of_the_skype_highlighting (773) 878-7340 FREE end_of_the_skype_highlighting

`=IF(FIND(",",C2),LEFT(C2,FIND("begin",C2)-2)&","&MID(C2,FIND(",",C2)+2,14),MID(C2,FIND("begin",C2)+2,14))`

i m above formula to extract the phone no.
like:

1. (423) 242-0045
2. (630) 472-1900, (773) 878-7340

but its working for 2. type of string but not 1st one.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Take a look at this. Help you rectify your formula.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula (assuming the input format fits the sample):

`=TRIM(LEFT(A1,14)&IFERROR(", "&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,14),""))`